# If $u\in L^p(R^N)\cap C(R^N)$, then $u\in L^\infty(R^N)$, is the conclusion is true?, thanks!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $u\in L^p(R^N)\cap C(R^N)$, then $u\in L^\infty(R^N)$, is the conclusion is true?thanks!

Comment: Please, provide some details. For example, state what do those notations stand for (the definitions) and your thoughts on why you think this conclusion could be true.

Comment: it's true if u is uniformly continuous as opposed to just continuous.

Comment: thank you vey much!

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Consider a function made up of "spikes": a triangular spike with base the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ and height $1$, a triangle with base $[1-1/2^3,1+1/2^3]$ and height $2$, a triangle with base $[2-1/2^5,2+1/2^5]$ and height $2^2$ etc. (and zero elsewhere, so continuous). The series of the areas $1/2+1/2^2+\dots$ is convergent so the function is in $L^1$. However, it is clearly not bounded since the heights of the triangles increases to infinity. A similar construction works for any $p\ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you,if we add a condition $\nabla u\in L^2$, is the result true?

Comment: I know that if $u$ and $\nabla u$ belong to $L^2$ (in other words, $u$ is in the Sobolev space $H^1$, then $u\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ and this plus continuity clearly implies $u\in L^\infty$. This holds in dimension 1. For other dimensions, see "Sobolev embedding".

Comment: thank you very much! if we revise the condition as $u\in C(R^3)\cap L^6(R^3)$ and $\nabla u\in L^2(R^3)$, is the result true? thank you very much,This problem has been bothering me for a long time, and I have consulted a lot of professors and have not found the great proof.